# How to add variable name in href url in HTML and the URL must redirect to HTML page and did not get affected by variable name

Tags: javascript, html

My Html code is

```html
<a href="file-name-where-it-should-redirect.html" onclick="location.href=this.href+'/variable_name';return false;">Data</a>
```

I want it to redirect to **file-name-where-it-should-redirect.html** with **variable name** and the html files are in local directory
For ex:**localdirectory/file-name-where-it-should-redirect.html/variable_name**

Answer (score 0):

You can/must store the `href` in a variable which you can then use with [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). Per default if you click on a link the browser wants to follow it, you can prevent it from doing so with using [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) something like this should work:

```html
<a href="file-name-where-it-should-redirect.html" onclick="event.preventDefault();var href = this.href; location.assign(href + '/variable_name') ">Data</a>
```

To check the link, open developer tools and go to network, you will then see something like:

[image]